# Invalid Ticket when closing orders

Tags: mql4

I'm trying to close all opened orders, they are all MarketOrders not PendingOrders and have SL and TP set to 0 so they shouldn't close themselves (they are still opened in Terminal). I am storing tickets in the array so my loop looks like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < trades.size(); ++i) OrderClose(tickets[i], lots[i], Bid, Slippage);
```

yet I'm still receiving "INVALID TICKET" error, can you tell me why?
It doesn't happen always, its like some orders are closed and some throw Invalid Ticket.
I didn't notice this behavior with only 1 order so I'm assuming it occurs only when there are more of them.

Code:

```
template < typename T >
struct vector {
  vector() {}
  vector(int arraySize) {
     if (arraySize < 0) { arraySize *= -1; }
     ArrayResize(m_data, arraySize);
  }
  vector(vector & rhs) { 
     if (size() < rhs.size()) { ArrayResize(m_data, rhs.size()); }
     for(uint i = 0; i < size(); ++i) { m_data[i] = rhs.m_data[i]; }
  }
  vector operator=(vector & rhs) {
     if (size() < rhs.size()) { ArrayResize(m_data, rhs.size()); }
     for(uint i = 0; i < size(); ++i) { m_data[i] = rhs.m_data[i]; }
     return this;
  }
  T operator[](uint index) { return m_data[index]; }
  void push_back( T value ) {

     ArrayResize(m_data, ArraySize(m_data) + 1); 
     m_data[ ArraySize(m_data) - 1 ] = value;
  }
  uint size() { return ArraySize(m_data); }
  void resize(uint newSize) { ArrayResize(m_data, newSize); }
  void erase() {
     ZeroMemory(m_data);
     ArrayResize(m_data, 0);
  }
  void assign(uint index, T value) {
     m_data[index] = value;
  }
private:
  T m_data[];
};

string Buy(double lots) {
  string alertString = "";
  int __ticket;
  if ( (__ticket = OrderSend (Symbol(), OP_BUY, lots, Ask, Slippage, 0, 0, NULL, m_magic)) != -1 )
  {
     m_buyTicket.push_back( __ticket );
     m_buyLots.push_back( lots );
     m_buyPrice.push_back( Ask );
     m_buyAccel.push_back( lots / Lots );
     m_buyPos.push_back( 0 );

     alertString = "Buy function call." +
            "\nAsk\t= " + (string)Round(Ask) +
            "\nBid\t= " + (string)Round(Bid) +
            "\nLots\t= " + (string)Round(lots) +
            "\nSpread\t= " + (string)m_spread +
            "\nID\t= " + (string)CountAll();
  }
  else { 
     int _error = GetLastError();
     alertString = "Error " + (string)_error + "\n" + TranslateError( _error );
  }
  return alertString;
}

string CloseAll() {
  string alertString = "CloseAll function call.";
  // Buy closing
  for (uint i = 0; i < m_buyPrice.size(); ++i)
  {
     if ( OrderClose ( m_buyTicket[i], m_buyLots[i], Bid, Slippage) )
     {
        alertString += "\nBuy " + (string)(i+1) + " closed with profit " +
                       (string)Shrink ( (Bid - m_buyPrice[i]) * m_buyAccel[i] );
     }
     else
     {
        int _error = GetLastError();
        alertString += "\nError " + (string)_error + "\n" + TranslateError( _error ) +
                       "\n(while closing Buy " + (string)(i+1) + ")";
     }
  }
  // Sell closing
  for (uint i = 0; i < m_sellPrice.size(); ++i)
  {
     if ( OrderClose ( m_sellTicket[i], m_sellLots[i], Ask, Slippage) )
     {
        alertString += "\nSell " + (string)(i+1) + " closed with profit " +
                       (string)Shrink ( (m_sellPrice[i] - Ask) * m_sellAccel[i] );
     }
     else
     {
        int _error = GetLastError();
        alertString += "\nError " + (string)_error + "\n" + TranslateError( _error ) +
                       "\n(while closing Sell " + (string)(i+1) + ")";
     }
  }
  return alertString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you close some ticket successfully, you do not remove it from the list `trades`, right? And it seems you should. Use your struct to clear the elements if order close is successful.
By the way, there's probably no need to reinvent the wheel, use `CArrayObj` as a container for your elements and delete them once order is closed.

Comment: Oh you are right, thank you :D I was calling erase() on other arrays but not on m_buyTicket and m_sellTicket arrays.

Comment: I would like to ask you 1 more question if you don't mind. Is the return value of OrderCommission() presented in Points or actual money like cents?

Comment: in your account currency, e.g. USD or EUR. Same thing for swaps.Many brokers do not have commission at all, it will be zero.